# Closest Metro Station into DC if coming from Eastern Shore/Bay Bridge?

Tags: trains, public-transport, washington-dc

Trying to plan a trip to DC, but am not at all familiar with the metro (other than it is the best trandportation to use in D.C.).  I'll be coming from the Eastern Shore (a.k.a. Fish and Farm Land, lol) and crossing the Bay Bridge, where should I go after I get off the bridge?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What days are you planning to visit? Because of ongoing problems and repair work, the Metro has been very unreliable outside of rush hour, with waits of 20-30 minutes bit uncommon on weekends. There will be station closures and massive further service reductions in August. See https://wmata.com/service/track-work.cfm

Comment: Within the city, the Circulator buses are a good alternative to the train, depending on where you want to go, and Capital Bikeshare or Lime bicycles are also extremely popular. There are some Bird scooters as well (for now) . I am a local who didn't own a car for 14 years, but the Metro had degraded so badly that it became faster to drive into the city even during rush hour than it was to take the train. I still avoid driving in the city, but almost exclusively use Lyft to get in and out in weekends now.

Answer (score 4):

If you cross the Chesapeake Bay Bridge you will be going westbound down US 50. And the eastern end of the Orange line, the New Carrollton station, is just off of US 50, so it is probably the fastest station to get to by driving.

Comment: Largo Town Center is also not too bad. It's just down 495 a piece.